# RecordActions with Process Builder- Appearing Multiple Times

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I have a Process Builder that creates a RecordAction of "Action Type" Flow, at various Opportunity Stages.The RecordAction correctly shows under Actions & Recommendations each time a matching Stage is reached.

Is there a recommended way to prevent a RecordAction from appearing more than once (that doesn't require apex or a custom field)?

[image]